# how to merge MainStroryBoard in xcode using GIT

Tags: swift, xcode, git

I am using GIT control for my project management under version control.
Me and my teammate is working on Branch1 and Branch2.
We both worked on Main Stroryboard of Xcode but different view controller files.
we are getting conflict while merging.

Comment: Resolve the conflicts, use `git add` on those files which were in conflict, then `git commit` and you are done.  Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: You just have to read the `code representation` of the .storyboard file and remove the conflicts. I've had experience doing this which is kind of a pain honestly. Which is why I use nibs on most of my layouts. And only use .storyboard if I can't do it on nib

Comment: Then do what @Tim said

Comment: when i merged the branches. I got error "line152:StartTag: invalid element name". when i tried to open Main Storyboard.